# Mimicking windows task manager performance graph

Tags: javascript

I am searching for a javascript library that can mimick the moving chart on the windows task manager Performance tab - CPU usage history.Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this:

- http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Here's a nice roundup of graphing libraries for JS:

- http://javascript.open-libraries.com/utilities/chart/20-best-javascript-charting-and-plotting-libraries/

I guess you would have to do some work in styling and of course provide data every second or whatever your interval is. Here's a similar example that has to do with that:

- [How to plot a realtime graph (histogram) using data obtained in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728937/how-to-plot-a-realtime-graph-histogram-using-data-obtained-in-a-text-file)

This seems to be a more complete example using flot:

- http://thomasbarker.com/10/03/java-recipe-realtime-graphing-js-and-bayeux.

Another flot example from SO:

- [Real Time data graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792750)

Comment: Flot looks good,but it seems i am going to have to animate the background.

Comment: I found this example:http://www.ejschart.com/examples/other/dynamicArray.html  and placed a grid background and it looked like what i had in mind.

Comment: I think flot has everything you need. You would need to take a look at the API docs - text file unfortunately - http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/API.txt.

Comment: Nice - the example you found looks exactly like what you've been looking for!

Comment: I will have a look at the Api,from what i am reading,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350056/real-time-graphing-with-flot-mysql-php  moving charts are pretty bandwidth intensive,have you had to apply them somewhere?.

Comment: I did not, but I suppose for 1 second charts it is going to be a lot of traffic. The problem is fragmentation - each byte that you send over to the web site needs to be padded like hell with various things (take a look http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_model). So you basically turn a dozen bytes that you need to send (x + y axis data) into hundreds of bytes that needs to be transferred over the physical wire. Here's the calc just for Ethernet http://sd.wareonearth.com/~phil/net/overhead/ and each layer adds a lot. If there are many clients, you may be in trouble...

Comment: Here's an even better example of how much more traffic is "wasted" compared to real data: http://www.tamos.net/~rhay/overhead/ip-packet-overhead.htm. But hey - you really need the additional information...